# For how long will the question be closed?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to know why the question is closed and I cannot edit it anymore? Because I planned to improve it. I mean I want to make the text question 100% clear without any mistakes, because I got an idea how to make clear. And can you tell me after that if it is OK how I corrected it? 
￼

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're talking about the question [Can I ask Allah To reverse the time till the moment He Will decide to create Pen?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43217/22), that is going to be closed until the community or a moderator decides that it's worth reopening. The advice in our help centre, particularly [How do I ask a good question?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) are worth checking out if you have not already.

As for why you can't edit it any more, that's because it's *also* been locked, the reasons for which were explained when I locked it:

> I am temporarily locking this question to prevent further edits; please take the time to actually think about what you want to ask before asking it (do feel free to discuss it on meta or in chat with others who are willing to help if you are unable to do so yourself), flooding the site with low-quality edits and poorly thought-out questions is disruptive and doesn't actually help anyone.

This lock was set for a week, and will expire naturally; you can edit your question again then. I see no reason to believe that your current "idea how to make clear" will be any better than the *[fifty-six](https://islam.stackexchange.com/posts/43217/revisions)* other edits you made to the question which have, if anything, made it even harder to understand what, if anything, you're looking for in an answer.

I strongly suggest you take this week to figure out what sorts of questions we *do* encourage here, *what* you actually want to ask and *how* to present it as a clear and focussed question that might actually have a chance of being reopened. The blocks and restrictions you're seeing when you try to ask poorly-formulated questions are there for a reason.

Comment: Even if it is “not worthy” it is just for me to know.

Comment: I was trying to make 100% clear text so that I’ll no longer get: on hold,unclear etc.. ,and if I fail can you please correct it? Only the last time and next time when I can ask again, I’ll try to not happen as now again.

Comment: Good guess, about this what I was talking about.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any post that have beem edited more than that?

Comment: @Medi1Saif Nothing that I know of on this site. You'll see edit chains that long on some of the really popular community wiki stuff on Stack Exchange or FAQ stuff on Meta.SE, but it's not a regular thing.